# NGRX selector in resolver

Tags: angular, ngrx

In my resolver I have:

```
export class ComicMainResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  store = new Observable<any>();

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(getItems(CategoryType.Comics, false, 'results')))
      .pipe(
        filter((comic: any) => {
          console.log(comic);
          return comic !== undefined;
        }), first());
  }
}
```

But it does not resolve, won't even log the var in the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that store is an empty Observable, instead, you need to inject your store and use it like this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComicMainResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(getItems(CategoryType.Comics, false, 'results')))
      .pipe(
        filter((comic: any) => {
          console.log(comic);
          return comic !== undefined;
        }), first());
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could do a face palm emoji. Thanks, I missed that